# Parsing packets captured using wireshark for management frames identification using libpcap or similar library

Tags: parsing, wireless, libpcap, packets

I want to parse packets captured by wireshark offline using libpcap. I am capturing packets from a wireless network in monitor mode. I have read that "libpcap" can be used to capture and parse packets captured in the ethernet. Can it be used for wireless networks too? If yes, can anyone suggest me some tutorial? and if No, which library is suitable for it and how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

libpcap, and its Windows port, WinPcap can be used to capture network traffic (in fact, they're what Wireshark uses to capture network traffic), as well as to read a capture file in pcap format (the default format for Wireshark's existing releases) and, in libpcap 1.1 and later, to read some capture files in pcap-ng format (the default format for the current development version of Wireshark; it should write out files that libpcap 1.1 and later can read).

They can handle a number of network types, including Ethernet and Wi-Fi.

They do not, however, support parsing *any* packet types; that's the job of the code that uses them, whether it's tcpdump/WinDump, Wireshark, or some other application.  There's a library called [WiFiPcap](http://www.jeffpang.net/software.shtml) that is:

> A C++ wrapper around libpcap that parses 802.11 frames, and the most common layer 3 (IPv4, IPv6, ARP) and layer 4 protocols (TCP, UDP, ICMP) contained within them. Also works without link-layer headers. Works in Linux and Windows.

(copied from its web page, but edited to fix the protocol layer numbers to match the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model)).

I have not looked at it, but it might do what you want.

There might also be other libraries that could be used to parse the packets.