# How can I parse a wifi packet with libpcap? (c++)

Tags: c++, wifi

I have a pipe that comes from another process that will spit out all wifi packets in the area. I need a way to parse the bytes and turn them into some sort of packet object that has src, destination, rssi and other such values. I would prefer to not have to write the processing myself (the wifi standard is over 1000 pages) but I can't find any library that will do this for me. Does anyone know of a library that can help with this?

I am using c++ do all the processing.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015514/parsing-packets-captured-using-wireshark-for-management-frames-identification-us

Comment: See: https://github.com/simsong/tcpflow/tree/master/src/wifipcap

Comment: Both of those actually end up talking about parsing ethernet frames. Ethernet is fundamentally different than wifi.

Comment: See my last comment. P.S. They are talking about Wifi packets